# I want to make character moves in my website when pressing arrow keys, but not sure what is required to achieve that

Tags: javascript, html, css, adobe-illustrator, after-effects

as in title, I want to make something similar to Super Mario but website (simple) version. That user could control the character movement by pressing arrow button.

My concept is when user press the arrow button it triggers the website to scroll horizontally & character walking animation so it would seems like the character is moving forward/backward.

However, I've tried searched tutorials online but couldn't find any ways to allow users to control the character via keyboard buttons.

I wonder can the movement control be done simply using css/javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us your attempts, and what part of your attempt isn't behaving the way you're expecting it to. This is not a code-writing service. We help with concrete questions about _your_ work.

Comment: I'm not expecting people to write code for me, I just need brief answers on where to start since I'm not sure what is required to achieve what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

you can use event listeners to achieve this....

for example:

```
let environment = document.getElementById('environment');
 
environment.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    let pressedKey = e.key;
// you can use the pressedKey to perform some actions 
// based on the key type, ie arrow keys
})
```